# Propongo poner un banner con referencia hacia Meta

Tags: característica-nueva, meta

La verdad me impresiona la cantidad de personas que han votado en las elecciones. Eso puede significar muchas cosas, pero me gustaría pensar que es porque hay muchas personas que estan interesadas en el sitio en si mismo y no solo en la información que este tiene o produce; siendo esto muy bueno.

En mi navegación por otros sitios de SE, me encontre con *Interpersonal Skills Beta*. Ellos tienen un banner fijo en la parte de arriba de su sitio que hace referencia a su Meta. No recuerdo haber visto otro sitio con esto.

[image: Interpersonal Skills beta]

Dada la cantidad de votos de las elecciones, quiero pensar que las personas no participan tanto en Meta, simplemente porque no saben que existe. Mi fundamento para decir esto es que revisé las listas de usuarios de SOes y Meta en la pestaña de votos del último año, en la primera hay 13 páginas de aprox. 36 usuarios cada una (aprox. 460 votantes activos) y en Meta solo hay 3 páginas de la misma cantidad de usuarios (aprox.  100 votantes activos). No estoy diciendo que todos deberian ser activos en Meta, pero vamos que la diferencia es significativa.

Propongo que se proponga (a quien sea pertinente, que no sé cómo funciona eso) implementar un banner sencillo, como el que se ve en la imagen, para que las personas sean conscientes de la existencia de Meta, puedan participar más y podamos mejorar la calidad del sitio en sí mismo.

Comment: En Meta hay que usar una de entre cuatro etiquetas obligatorias. La de discusión es para pedir opinión, la de característica nueva, es para proponer cambios, etc. La redacción debería concordar con la etiqueta y como dices que propones, he quitado la etiqueta discusión. En cuanto a cómo funciona esto lee [¿Qué es Meta y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Gracias @Ruben.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El banner que aparecía en [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) dice:

> got a question about the site itself? meta.XX is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.

Y aparece en la parte superior de un sitio durante sus 30 primeros días de vida ([referencia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293057/209901)). Tiene su sentido en tanto en cuanto en esos primeros días hay un influjo grande de nuevos usuarios (normalmente gente ya registrada en otros sitios de la red Stack Exchange) y es uno de los momentos clave para perfilar la temática y maneras de hacer del sitio.

Una vez el sitio está en marcha, y especialmente graduado como SOes, se supone que esas urgencias ya quedaron resueltas y los debates son más puntuales y de forma más orgánica. La estructura ya está dada y todo el foco se da en las preguntas y las respuestas.

Seguramente un tanto por ciento muy grande de nuestros visitantes no tengan ningún interés, ni tampoco necesidad, de Meta, por lo que no creo que haya necesidad de sugerirles que entren allí. Podría ser incluso contraproducente en cuanto a que podría confundir.

Además, un banner permanente... deja de verse. De ahí que sí tengamos un recuadro a la derecha que va rotando con los elementos más destacados de Meta.

Lo que sí te animo a hacer es abrir debates cuando sea pertinente e involucrar a los afectados con comentarios en sus publicaciones en el sitio principal.

Comment: No sabia eso de los 30 primeros dias. Como solo era una propuesta veo que no es una buena idea. Estoy muy satisfecho con la respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias a ti por plantearlo, @Kenny